# geometry nodes - dual mesh transfer material setting

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

in geometry nodes - when using dual mesh node the geometry looses any material assignment.

I can find set material node but no get material node - how to transfer previous material setting so it's not lost after dual mesh node?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new when it comes to geometry nodes but in my basic example it seems like you can use vertex groups to reassign materials: [image]